# Pressure sensitive drawing software in Linux

Tags: linux, drawing

What pressure sensitive drawing software that works in Linux?

I'm looking for one that works like Windows' [Corel Painter](http://www.painterartist.com/us/product/paint-program/) for drawing comic/manga, I need features such as:

- pressure sensitive
- layers
- multiple/custom brushes

and probably out of topic, what hardware (which drawing tablets) that could work together with that software on Linux?

My purpose is to create comic/manga. Free software is preferable, but a reasonable price would be fine as well.

Please answer based on your experience.

Comment: Hi, we expect all answers here on SO to be based on experience :) Also, could you add what you would be willing to pay for the software? Does it need to be Open source or don't you care? Are there any other features you would like with that software? For example gsumi would fit the description, but only does black and white drawings, would that match your needs? (I have no experience with it, just a quick search of "pressure sensitive drawing linux")

Comment: paid or free no problem..

Comment: grayscale or color would be ok..

Comment: for the hardware I think I'll go for https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Genius_Tablet some said it works http://askubuntu.com/a/552235/112428

Comment: That makes the question rather broad. Currently all pressure sensitive drawing tools on linux would match. Please have a look at this [meta discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Software Recommendation aims at being more than just an extension of your search engine, we want specific problems that have specific solutions.

Comment: my purpose is to create comic/manga ^^

Comment: Okay, please [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/17116/edit) your question to contain that information, together with other requirements you have (like macros? Auto-panel setting? Layers? Different pencil shapes? Intensity control? Stuff like that?). If you don't know yet, just try one of the tools that a simple search turns up and see if it fits your needs. If yes: great. If not, you now know what to ask. In both cases you then can write a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) supports a number of tablets *but you do need to [configure](https://inkscape.org/doc/calligraphy/tutorial-calligraphy.html) the pressure response*
- [Krita](https://krita.org/) also supports various [tablets](https://krita.org/about/faq/)

Both are Free, cross platform and should meet your needs - I have limited experience of using either with a tablet as my hand never goes where I think it should - *even with pencil and paper* - but think that Krita is probably more suited to your needs.

Comment: too bad [Medibang Paint Pro](https://medibangpaint.com/en/pc/) doesn't support linux, but now i'm using windows to paint..

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered an application called 'Write': not the most original or SEO friendly name, but it is what it is.

I have an HP Spectre x360, and the application supports pressure sensitivity, in fact it feels better than Windows Ink Workspace sketchpad, at least for my way of using the pen. This means I can use much less pressure than in windows, and the result looks more natural.

Link here: http://www.styluslabs.com/